# I want to copy only changed files in my git repo that is shown by git diff command to a folder of same structure as in git repo using groovy

Tags: git, groovy

I just want to copy only the changed files shown by the output of git diff command at groovy console.However this code is copying all the files and folder of 'C:/git/dev1/server'.

```
def command2 = "git diff --stat @{12.hours.ago}"
Process process = command2.execute(null, new File('C:/git/dev1/server'))
println "Std Err: ${process.err.text}"
println "Std Out: ${process.in.text}"

def sourceDir ="C:/git/dev1/server"
def destinationDir ="D:/demo1"
new AntBuilder().copy(todir: destinationDir) {
fileset(dir: sourceDir) }


}
```

Comment: And what error do you get?  What does not work?

Comment: I am not getting error.This code is copying all the files and folders to destination.However i want to copy the files that are given by output of command2 = "git diff --stat @{12.hours.ago}...@cfrick

Comment: @rohit.dagur, please edit your question: provide the example of output of git command. ask the question or describe a problem. `I'm new to ..` - is not a problem.

Comment: @dagett...edited the question...output of groovy console is ...  Sports/Cricket/Venue/Eden.txt | 3 ++-
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

     [copy] Copying 17 files to D:\demo1

Comment: however i want to copy only changed file which is Sports/Cricket/Venue/Eden.txt in my case.......@dagett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already told you in your other question, you should not use porcellain commands for scripting actions. If you use `git diff --stat`, the process can hang forever if you get enough output to be more than one page, bcause then the pager process (`less` by default) is started, paths will be abbreviated if long enough, output and parameters might be instable between different Git versions and so on.

Instead you have to use some plumbing command or variant that is meant for script consumptions, does not "suffer" from the things specific for porcellain commands and should be pretty stable between Git versions usually.

Also you don't have to just consider copying over files, there could also be files that get deleted. So what you need is something like the following to reliably do what you want:

```
['git', 'diff', '--raw', '--no-renames', '@{12.hours.ago}']
    .execute(null, new File('C:/git/dev1/server'))
    .text
    .readLines()
    .collect() { it.split(' ')[4].split('\t') as List }
    .each { action, file ->
        if (action == 'D') {
            Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("D:/demo1/$file"))
        } else {
            Files.copy(Paths.get("C:/git/dev1/server/$file"), Paths.get("D:/demo1/$file"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
        }
    }
```